# Estimate error in approximating integral with sum

Tags: definite-integrals, summation

In a paper, for practical purposes the following integral is approximated as a sum,
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(\theta) e^{-il\theta}d \theta \approx \frac{1}{M}\sum_{v=1}^{M}f(v\Delta\theta)e^{-ilv\Delta\theta}
$$
It is given an expression for the estimated error
$$
err= -\frac{2 \pi^3}{3M^2} \frac{d^2 f(\theta) e^{-il\theta}}{d\theta^2} \sim -\frac{2 \pi^3 l^2}{3M^2} 
$$
but no references are given on how the expression is found. Any ideas? Have you seen it elsewhere?

For completeness, here it is the paper [(link, Eqs. 23-24)](http://iopscience.iop.org/1367-2630/14/11/115005), even though it is not really usefull to read it.

Comment: Did you have a look at the [errors for Riemann sums?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Methods)

Comment: It must be that formula, I wasn't aware of these methods, thanks.